# Synthetic landscape 360 degree

Tags: java, android, c++, vb6, vb4android

Does anyone have experience about SRTM or HGT or DEM files ("DIGITAL ELEVATION DATA") with you can create a static and synthetic landscape of the type of the image :
http://www.lalpinistavirtuale.it/Panorami/Ronce_sintetico.jpg
I would like to discuss that (algorithms, drawing mode, etc..)
Thanks for any information

Answer (score 1):

Given elevation data, i.e. a height map, you can generate a 3D mesh made of triangles. This is a technique commonly used in video game development, and you should have no problem finding sample code for doing so online (one place you could look is in the terrain generators of the [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) or [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/) graphics engines).

You could then use [Android's OpenGL support](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) to render these meshes into a virtual landscape like the one you linked.

You could then just move the virtual camera around your generated world. Or, if you want to generate a panorama, just keep the camera in one location, then rotate around, rendering images. Since you know the azimuth at which you rendered each image, combining them should be fairly trivial.